# Edit Jar file with xml or properties file in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have an own .jar file with some configuration about OAuth2 and Spring security Server. Now I want to edit file .xml in it to suitable with my project (like url, value, name). So do we have any way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't nor should. You want to externalize that information in a properties file and then modify that properties file (which is outside your jar). You don't want to touch your jar.

Comment: Yes, I use properties file to modify the xml file external of that jar file and it's success. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to externalize your properties into a property file, web container (tomcat, jboss)enviroment variables or SO enviroment variables.

Then you need to tell Spring where your properties are located

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${app.home}/app.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
}
```

Here there are some tutorials

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

Comment: I didn't try this way because I defined that information in properties file. It's work for jar file. Anyway, thank you :D